# Geometry node : move curve's endpoint along tangent

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to move a curve's endpoint outwards along its tangent with geometry node, do you think it's possible?

pretty much like this

[image]

thank you

Comment: `Set Position` selected with `Endpoint Selection` feeded with `Curve Tangent` scaled by $X$?

Comment: Yes it was actually this simple. I was trying to get the curve tangent with the capture atribute node and it wouldn't work. Thank you

Comment: Does one of you fancy posting the solution in the comment as a quick little  answer? Or shall we wind the question up? I would do it myself, but don't want to intrude :)

Comment: @RobinBetts I just did post an answer

Comment: @Alex Cheers! After a while, you can accept it, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to work thanks to @quellenform with this simple setup :

[image]

The scale value will move the curve's endpoint along its tangent